# printing the backtrace at the point an exception was thrown in the catch block

Tags: c++, exception, stack-trace, backtrace

I want to print the backtrace of an exception (the state at the point is where was thrown), but in a catch block.

I am also just targetting gcc, but would like to keep unportable code to a minimum (I know the stack printing code I show in my examples is non-portable).

From what I understood so far, in the catch block the stack was already partially unwond, so it is no longer there to be read.
To be fair, it should still be there (in memory), if no local variables are created and no method calls are done, but I'm not sure how safe I would be trying to read it this way.

I also noticed that if I register a terminate method (via std::set_terminate) and have no catch block, then the full stack at the point where the unhandled exception was thrown is available to the handler. I'm guessing this is because it was unwound totally, but the original values in the stack was not overwritten (and most likely the terminate handler somehow has an indepentent call stack).

I tested this under gcc:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <execinfo.h>

using namespace std;

void handler()
{
    void *trace_elems[20];
    int trace_elem_count(backtrace(trace_elems, 20));
    char **stack_syms(backtrace_symbols(trace_elems, trace_elem_count));
    for(int i=0 ; i != trace_elem_count; ++i)
    {
        cout << stack_syms[i] << "\n";
    }
    free(stack_syms);

    exit(1);
}

void level3() { throw std::runtime_error("oops"); }
void level2() { level3(); }
void level1() { level2(); }
```

If I use it like this, the exception backtrace is lost (only main and handler are in the call stack):

```
void main()
{
    try { level1(); }
    catch(...) { handler();}
}
```

But if I call it like this, the backtrace at the point the exception was thrown is printed:

```
void main()
{
    std::set_terminate(handler);
    level1();
}
```

Some context on my use case: I have two running processes, one produces requests and the other will process them. The execution of these requests can sometimes result in exceptions. At that point the backtrace is usefull to figure out why it failed (what() very often does not have enough information), but I cannot let the exception reach main, since both processes need to continue working. I just need to print the backtrace and return a message signalling failure to execute.

**EDIT:** A common solution, that is being suggested to this problem is having a base exception class that captures the call stack on construction, and has it available to print out later. This is certainly a possible solution (and one I might have to resort to, if no better solution is found).

I am avoiding it at the moment because:

1. It adds some (considerable) overhead to capture the call stack at the moment I throw the exception
2. I have a relatively high percentage of cases where I can actually handle the exception before having to give up and print the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom exception class, that would in its constructor, call `backtrace` and store the buffer within itself.

When caught, such exception would have the required data to print the trace. In fact, the handler could well be a member function of the exception. Note that the trace would include the extra call to the constructor of the exception.

This works as long as you only throw the custom exception or exceptions derived from it.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility, but I wanted to avoid it, since it adds some (considerable) overhead to throwing an exception, and forces me to change all the code that could throw to use it. Also, I have a high percentage of cases where I can actually handle the exception before having to give up and print the stack trace.

Comment: @RuiPires well, if you're going to print the trace, then the overhead is going to be there anyway. If you're not going to print the trace, then you can keep throwing the regular exceptions that don't capture the trace. Indeed, since the trace has to be captured at the point of throwing, that is where you have to decide whether you're going to capture it.

Comment: Yes, that is my dilemma, I don't really know if I will be able to handle it at the point where I throw it. I'll have to end up deciding something, but was hoping to avoid the overhead (it bugs me that the information is there, but apparently  just out of reach).

Answer (score 0):

Best I can suggest is to collect the stack trace at the point of the throw.

This code may need a little refining, but it should give you an idea:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

#include <execinfo.h>

using namespace std;


inline
auto make_stack_trace(int depth = 20) {
    auto trace_elems = std::vector<void *>(depth);
    auto trace_elem_count = backtrace(trace_elems.data(), depth);
    char **stack_syms = backtrace_symbols(trace_elems.data(), trace_elem_count);

    std::vector<std::string> symbols;
    symbols.reserve(trace_elem_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < trace_elem_count; ++i) {
        symbols.emplace_back(stack_syms[i]);
    }
    free(stack_syms);

    return symbols;
}

struct tracer {
    tracer(const std::vector<std::string> &trace)
            : trace_(trace) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const tracer &t) {
        const char *sep = "";
        for (const auto &line : t.trace_) {
            os << sep << line;
            sep = "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }

    const std::vector<std::string> &trace_;
};

struct has_stack_trace {
    has_stack_trace(std::vector<std::string> trace) : trace_(std::move(trace)) {}

    auto trace() const {
        return tracer(trace_);
    }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> trace_;
};

template<class Exception>
struct with_stack_trace : has_stack_trace, Exception {
    template<class...Args>
    with_stack_trace(Args &&...args)
            : has_stack_trace(make_stack_trace()), Exception(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
    }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return Exception::what();
    }

};


void level3() { throw with_stack_trace<std::runtime_error>("oops"); }

void level2() { level3(); }

void level1() { level2(); }


int main() {
    try {
        level1();
    }
    catch (has_stack_trace const &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.trace() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
oops
0   parallel-find                       0x000000010bad09e9 _Z16make_stack_tracei + 105
1   parallel-find                       0x000000010bad08ec _ZN16with_stack_traceISt13runtime_errorEC2IJRA5_KcEEEDpOT_ + 44
2   parallel-find                       0x000000010bacf46d _ZN16with_stack_traceISt13runtime_errorEC1IJRA5_KcEEEDpOT_ + 29
3   parallel-find                       0x000000010bacf40a _Z6level3v + 42
4   parallel-find                       0x000000010bacf4a9 _Z6level2v + 9
5   parallel-find                       0x000000010bacf4b9 _Z6level1v + 9
6   parallel-find                       0x000000010bacf4d7 main + 23
7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffa6346255 start + 1
8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility (and a common solution to this problem). I wanted to avoid it, since it adds some (considerable) overhead to throwing an exception. Also, I have a high percentage of cases where I can actually handle the exception before having to give up and print the stack trace. I will add this to the question, since it restricts the kind of answer I'm looking for. Thank you for the sample code!

Comment: @RuiPires the other thing that springs to mind is the idea of some kind of thread_local context stack which determines throw/catch behaviour. i.e. each context knows which exceptions it can handle and builds a stack trace otherwise. Again, there is overhead - this time in the non-exceptional paths (much worse!). Perhaps this is why there is no stack trace in std exceptions. The idiomatic way of course is to use nested exceptions. Then the overhead is only on the exceptional path.